# Why PySpark execute only the default statement in my custom `SQLTransformer`

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I wrote a custom `SQLTransformer` in PySpark. And setting a default SQL statement is mandatory to have the code being executed. I can save the custum transformer within Python, load it and execute it using Scala or/and Python but only the default statement is executed despite the fact that there is something else in the `_transform` method. I have the same result for both languages, then the problem is not related to `_to_java` method or  `JavaTransformer` class.

```py
class filter(SQLTransformer): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(filter, self).__init__() 
        self._setDefault(statement = "select text, label from __THIS__") 

    def _transform(self, df): 
        df = df.filter(df.id > 23)
        return df
```

Comment: I need to call the `SQLTransformer` in a Scala pipeline. I can save the `SQLTransformer` within Python, load and run it in the Scala side, but despite the fact that I define a `_transform` method in the class, the default statement is executed in the Scala side.

Answer (score 1):

Such information flow is not supported. To create a `Tranformer` that can be used with both Python and Scala code base you have:

- Implement Java or Scala `Transformer`, in your case extending `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer`.
- Add Python wrapper extending `pyspark.sql.ml.wrapper.JavaTransformer` the same way as `pyspark.sql.ml.feature.SQLTransformer` and interface JVM counterpart from it.

Comment: Thanks, that's to say that custom Transformer written in Python can not be used in  a Scala pipeline. Because, If I need to write the same code in Scala and in Python, better use directly what is already written in Scala in my Scala pipeline.